# How to have AWS Amplify ignore my developer account credentials from AWS CLI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm developing an SPA using React and Amplify, and trying to write tests around various authentication states. I use Cognito as my auth provider.

My tests for the condition where the user is signed out but attempting to access an s3 resource are failing, because `Auth.currentCredentials()` is returning my developer user IAM credentials configured via AWS CLI (`aws configure`) on the machine I'm using to run tests.

```
  await Auth.signOut();
  Auth.currentCredentials()
    .then(credentials => {
      const s3 = new S3({
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials),
        signatureVersion: 'v4',
        region: 'us-east-1'
      });
      s3.getSignedUrl(
        'getObject',
        {
          Bucket: 'myBucket',
          Key:'myKey'
        },
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('got data: ', data);
            //a presigned URL is returned which successfully accesses content
          }
        }
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      //where I expect code to reach
    });
```

How can I isolate my developer creds from Amplify, forcing it to only look at temporary session-based creds from Cognito? If it matters, I'm developing in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Remove default profile from AWS CLI, depending on os something like (UserHomeDirectory) /. Aws/credentials file..

You can just update file to change default to another name.. Then when you want it set profile..